# How to pass values into a matrix with discontinuous index in parfor loop

Tags: matlab, indexing, parfor

I have met a problem when passing values into specific position in a matrix in parfor loop.
for example:

```
    array2 = zeros(6,3);
    ind = [1,3,5];
    parfor i=1:3
        array1 = [1,2,3;4,5,6]; % generated from function x(i);
        array2(ind(i):ind(i)+1,1:3) = array1(1:2,1:3);
    end
```

One function will calculate and generate different array1 for different i.
I want to save all the results into array2.
When I used a simple for loop, it worked well. But when I tried to apply parfor loop, the Error came: Error: The variable array2 in a parfor cannot be classified.
Can anyone provide a way to circumvent this problem?
many thanks!

Comment: calculate separate `array2`s and then combine them correctly after the `parfor`?

Comment: my problem is that different array1 will be generated for different i. how can i save all the arrray1s into array2?

Comment: save all the `array1`s separately with their `i` value to identify them and then recompile `array2` after the `parfor`?